# I'm using wp residence theme and want to display titile above the slider

Tags: theme-development, wp-admin

```php
<?php
global $align;
global $wpestate_options;
global $is_shortcode;
global $row_number_col;
$title          =   get_the_title();
$col_data       =   wpestate_return_unit_class($wpestate_no_listins_per_row,$wpestate_options['content_class'],$align,$is_shortcode,$row_number_col,$wpestate_property_unit_slider);
$link           =   esc_url( get_permalink() );
$main_image     =   wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'listing_full_slider');
?>  
<div class="<?php echo esc_html($col_data['col_class']);?> listing_wrapper " 
    data-org="<?php echo esc_attr($col_data['col_org']);?>"   
    data-main-title="<?php echo esc_attr($title);?>"
    data-main-modal="<?php echo esc_attr($main_image[1]); ?>"
    data-modal-link="<?php echo esc_attr($link);?>"
    data-listid="<?php echo intval($post->ID);?>" >        
    <div class="property_listing  property_card_default <?php echo wpestate_interior_classes($wpestate_uset_unit); ?> " 
         data-link="<?php   if(  $wpestate_property_unit_slider==0){ echo esc_url($link);}?>">

        <?php if ($wpestate_uset_unit==1) {
            wpestate_build_unit_custom_structure($wpestate_custom_unit_structure,$post->ID,$wpestate_property_unit_slider);
        } else { ?>  
           <div class="listing-unit-img-wrapper">
               <div class="prop_new_details">
                   <div class="prop_new_details_back"></div>       
                   <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_media_details');?>
                   <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_location');?>
                   <div class="featured_gradient"></div>
               </div>  
               <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_slider');?>
               <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_tags'); ?>
           </div>

           <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_title'); ?>    
           <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_price'); ?>
           <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_content'); ?>
           <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_details_default'); ?>

           <div class="property_location">
               <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_agent_details_default'); ?>
               <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_actions_type_default'); ?>
           </div>
        <?php
        }// end if custom structure
        ?>
    </div>             
</div>
```

I'm using wp residence theme and want to display title above the image slider

Comment: What did you try to achieve this and what happened?.. share some code in order to get some help.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to swap two of the template parts.  You want to take `<?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_title'); ?>` line and move it above the template include line that adds the slider.  I have no idea what this will do to your formatting but if you're this deep into the template then you should be pretty comfortable with CSS.

```
    <?php
    global $align;
    global $wpestate_options;
    global $is_shortcode;
    global $row_number_col;
    $title          =   get_the_title();
    $col_data       =   wpestate_return_unit_class($wpestate_no_listins_per_row,$wpestate_options['content_class'],$align,$is_shortcode,$row_number_col,$wpestate_property_unit_slider);
    $link           =   esc_url( get_permalink() );
    $main_image     =   wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'listing_full_slider');
    ?>
    <div class="<?php echo esc_html($col_data['col_class']);?> listing_wrapper " 
        data-org="<?php echo esc_attr($col_data['col_org']);?>"   
        data-main-title="<?php echo esc_attr($title);?>"
        data-main-modal="<?php echo esc_attr($main_image[1]); ?>"
         data-modal-link="<?php echo esc_attr($link);?>"
        data-listid="<?php echo intval($post->ID);?>" >      
        <div class="property_listing  property_card_default <?php echo wpestate_interior_classes($wpestate_uset_unit); ?> " 
             data-link="<?php if(  $wpestate_property_unit_slider==0){ echo esc_url($link);}?>">    
            <?php if( $wpestate_uset_unit==1 ){ wpestate_build_unit_custom_structure($wpestate_custom_unit_structure,$post->ID,$wpestate_property_unit_slider);
            } else{ ?>        
                    <div class="listing-unit-img-wrapper">
                        <div class="prop_new_details">
                            <div class="prop_new_details_back"></div>       
                            <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_media_details');?>
                            <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_location');?>
                            <div class="featured_gradient"></div>
                        </div> 
                        <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_title'); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_slider');?>
                        <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_tags'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_price'); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_content'); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_details_default'); ?>
                   
                    <div class="property_location">
                        <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_agent_details_default'); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part('templates/property_cards_templates/property_card_actions_type_default'); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }// end if custom structure
                ?>
            </div>             
        </div>
```